# Typescript object runtime check with a twist

Tags: typescript, typechecking

I have a server application that gets input data, as javascript objects. I need to check whether these data fullfills the requirements like:

- it has required fields defined by an interface
- these fields are certain types
- the object has only the listed fields, nothing else

I've found 2 libraries that very helpful for the goals:

Library [runtypes](https://github.com/pelotom/runtypes) and [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/blob/master/Type.md#recursive-types)

For example using **runtypes** i can create runtime types:

```
const PropSchema = Record({
    uid: String,
    name: String,
    timestamp: Number
});
```

And I can create a static type from PropSchema:

```
type PropSchemaInterface = Static<typeof PropSchema>;
```

From now on, I can use it as if it was an interface, typescript will warn if an object is invalid:

```
let props: PropSchemaInterface = { // this is invalid, because name is not a string
    uid: "31293-a7aa216982678",
    name: 4,
    timestamp: (new Date()).valueOf()
}
```

and check if an object fulfills PropSchema:

```
PropSchema.check(props); // returns true
```

but

```
PropSchema.check({
    uid: "12"
});
```

throws an error because name and timestamp does not exist in the provided object. That's very nice. But I really need to check whether the input object has only the fields defined in PropSchema, and nothing else. I could not find a way how to, because using this schema:

```
PropsSchema.check({
    uid: "123-123123123",
    name: "John Snow",
    timestamp: 123123123,
    someKey: "somevalue"
});
```

also returns true, as the provided object fulfills PropSchemaInterface, but for me it's an invalid object, because it has an unknown key: someKey. I could not find any library that can verify it for me.

**Is there any way to validate objects the way I want?** Runtypes is a really useful library as it's possible to have both *Runtime* and *Compile time* validation using the same descriptor (**PropSchema**), and I don't need to define it twice, but I could not figure out how to check for invalid object members. IO-TS has the same ability, but i did not try it so far.

Comment: Are you asking about what libraries to use or do you want to write code to do this yourself?  Either way I'd encourage you to provide a [mcve] that either has no third-party dependencies like io-ts or runtypes, or has such dependencies already configured in a web IDE you can link us to.  Right now it's too much work for me to try to set that up myself to play around with it and make concrete suggestions.

Comment: Agreed please modify your question and make it specific to runtypes, I just created the tag if you need. Question like 'is this lib better than this other lib ?' should not be asked on stackoverflow. Please have a look at the guidelines if you want.

Comment: i thought the question is clear: is there any library that can do runtime checking AND ability of filtering object having non existent members?

Answer (score 0):

The author of `runtypes` provides an excellent explanation of why extraneous types are allowed and "exact" types not currently supported in [his reply to this issue](https://github.com/pelotom/runtypes/issues/41#issuecomment-367415954).

If you read down to the bottom of that issue (at the time of writing this 2021-01-12) you can see that there's a PR pending to add this as a feature. Once that feature is added then using this would solve your problem and be the best solution.

In the meantime, if I were in your position, I would add a second validation step against your objects that would manually iterate through your objects and validate that no extraneous props are in there. It's a pain but the only short term workaround that I can think of until this PR is merged.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's exactly what I've done. I completely understand why Runtypes does not check fields strictly, but this feature is highly required, and I really think not just by me.